# Any way to identify page or device level Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)

Tags: technical-seo, core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

Have been trying to improve my sites mobile CLS score for the SEO benefits that it may or may not bring.

But getting discrepencies with tests that I can run vs real world data that google uses.

https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbritishop.com%2Fshop&hl=en_GB

Looking at mobile results, the real world URL test says 0.27, the real world origin says 0.2 and the simulated lab environment says 0

Any page test I run now shows a CLS of 0 (perfect) but the score google uses just isn't improving. I know about the 28 day lag time, but has been longer since I rolled out final optimisations to get a perfect score.

Best guess is there is a specific device or resolutution that creates a less optimal score in real world usage, any tools that can run mass simulations to identify this?

Chrome UX Report and CRUX API have historical data, but only percentages rather than any individual requests.

Comment: The field results will also include CLS that happens during user interaction. Have you tested for that?

Comment: I'd recommend reading this post, which explains all the various reasons why lab and field data could be different for each of the Core Web Vitals metrics: https://web.dev/lab-and-field-data-differences/